# Does the FBI accept applicants with any job background?

Tags: united-states, fbi

Does the FBI hiring teams allow people with any job background to apply to a position? More specifically, would the FBI allow or not allow someone with a political background to have a job in the organization? By political background I mean they have worked for a politician's office as say a staff assistant, legislative director/assistant, press secretary, etc.

Comment: Not an answer since I'm not a legal expert, but I'm pretty sure the government discriminating against people who'd participated in protected speech would be a violation of first amendment rights.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the specialized question of "political background", it appears that there is NO **published** disqualification of an applicant for having any sort of political background.

Here are the Entry Requirements: [FBI Applicant Qualifications](https://www.fbiagentedu.org/careers/fbi-special-agent/become-special-agent-with-fbi/)

> #### How To Become a Special Agent with the FBI
>
> The basic qualifications to become a FBI Special Agent are rigorous and include the following:
>
> - Be a U.S. citizen or a citizen of the Northern Mariana Islands
> - Be between 23 and 37 years of age, unless seeking a veteran’s waiver
> - Possess a bachelor’s degree from an accredited four year college
> - Possess a valid state driver’s license
> - Have worked as a professional for at least three years
>
> #### Qualifications for Special Agent Entry Programs
>
> In order to apply to become a Special Agent, the candidate must meet the qualifications for one of five Special Agent Entry Programs:
>
> - Accounting: Must possess CPA Certification, hold a four year degree in Accounting, or worked for three years in an accounting profession.
> - Computer science/Information Technology: Must possess a bachelor’s degree in an IT discipline.  Applicants should also possess a Cisco Certified Network Professional (CCNP) Certification or a Cisco Certified Internetworking Expert (CCIE) certification.
> - Language: Possess a four-year degree and proficiency in a critical foreign language specified by the FBI. Applicants must demonstrate competencies in reading, writing, speaking and translating. Presently languages include
>
>   - Arabic
>   - Chinese
>   - Farsi
>   - Hebrew
>   - Hindi
>   - Japanese
>   - Korean
>   - Pashtu
>   - Punjabi
>   - Russian
>   - Spanish
>   - Urdu
>   - Vietnamese
> - Law: Applicants must possess a JD degree from an accredited law school.
> - Diversified: Candidates must possess a bachelor’s degree in any concentration with three years of professional experience, or a master’s degree, JD degree, or PhD along with two years of professional experience.

Comment: So, would the FBI allow someone with a political background to have a job?

Comment: @BobE is "Special Agent" the only kind of employee the FBI hires? Do you need all those qualifications when you are working in accounting or facility management at the FBI? It also doesn't answer the question whether a political history is relevant.

Comment: @Philipp  Special Agent is the FBI equivalent of what a municipal police department would call officer.  I don't know that facilities management would address the asker's question--is there a big worry that janitors are overly political?  And as I read the requirements, they are five sets of alternatives.  Someone could enter the FBI as Law, Diversified (which probably also involves being female or minority, although that's not mentioned here), accounting, IT, or language candidate.  Of course, this answer doesn't really address unlisted requirements, like those to meet the diversity label.